# Can we rescue this systemd content?

Tags: discussion

- [Is it possible to "stop" a particular unit in juju?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519336/is-it-possible-to-stop-a-particular-unit-in-juju)

There is a really good writeup on systemd units here, which is unrelated to the original question but still good content: https://askubuntu.com/a/522630

Unfortunately I cannot leave a comment to the author because he deleted his post.

Comment: Umm... are you talking about the answer?

Comment: So, did anything come out of this?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, if you can still see the answer, post a question that fits the answer (share-your-knowledge) and mark the answer as a community wiki. I'd support that if the answer is good.